# Wifi function key not working on HP laptop

Tags: wireless, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 13.10

I have an HP Pavilion g7-1260 with Ubuntu 13.10 on it. I would like to be able to use the wifi toggle key on the keyboard to enable and disable wifi. My wifi works fine and the light on the key turns on when I enable wifi through the Ubuntu networking menu. The problem is that pressing the key does not do anything. It should be activated when I press `fn + f12`. I tried using `xev` to see if an event was generated but there wasn't one. I also tried the same thing with `apci_listen` but it didn't output anything. Does anyone know how to get the key to work?

Comment: Can you turn off the wireless with sudo rfkill block all? And back on with sudo rfkill unblock all? If so, I suggest you implement this method: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558&p=12819607#post12819607

Comment: I can enable and disable it using this method, but the problem is not that the wifi can't turn on and off, its that the key doesn't produce any events that I can bind to.

Comment: I understand that and that was the exact same case in the link I provided. The idea is to get some *other* key to implement 'rfkill block all' and still another key to implement 'rfkill unblock all.'

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you are talking about. The difference is that my laptop is an HP so it uses the `hp-wmi` module. I don't know if the configuration would be similar or not but I'll try it.

Comment: I doubt you need do anything with hp-wmi. That's the module that *doesn't* work properly.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying hp-wmi doesn't work?

Comment: In your case, it does not work. It is supposed to but, as you've seen, does not translate Fn+F2 (or whatever your wireless key combination is) into "turn on the wireless, please."

Comment: I filed a bug about this and I'm seeing if I can try to sort it out.